# 4CIF H263 video fails to decode

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to decode a H263 4CIF(704x576) resolution file with ffmpeg, but it is detected as mp3 file and fails to get decoded. I tried with lower resolution H263 files they get decoded easily as well as 16CIF. I am using ffmpeg version 0.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force ffmpeg to use a particular format for an input file by specifying `-f <fmt>` before the `-i <input file>` flag.